# PHP Form action(POST) doesn't send to other page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an issue with my form.

Here's my form structure.

```
<form method="POST" action="../login.php">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="test">
</form>
```

It's really only that.

But on my login page, it cannot get the POST parameter, and error logs says nothing.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    echo "true";
}
else {
    echo "false";
}
```

^^ That's my php code, right there. I've also tried with

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){}
```

Instead of isset.

Can anyone see what i do wrong here??

Kind regards

Comment: Can you try to dump your post array? `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot.

Comment: It's just empty. > array(0) { } @KoenHollander

Comment: Can you try put in a hidden field with a default value in the form and see if that goes through?

Comment: Can you please let us know if the login.php script is one level above in the folder structure as this script ?

Comment: At what path is this file related to your login file? `action="../login.php"` should perhaps be `action="login.php"` if it's in the same folder.

Comment: Is ```../login.php``` the correct path?

Comment: And do you get the same result when you try it without the `../` (just to be sure that is isn't the problem)

Comment: @KoenHollander - its the exact same result there. The path is right..

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure? Do you get the output "false"?

Comment: @Qirel there is over 120 files ;) The path is right as i can see.. I get the output false, with no items in post

Comment: I don't think folder structure is the problem here. If the redirect is there, then the folder structure is ok. I also tested `form method="POST" action="../../test.php"` and `form method="POST" action="test.php"` and even `form method="POST" action="../../../test.php"`. All of them work ok if the files are in one folder. And i have a question: Are you by any chance executing `login.php` without executing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

open login.php directly from URL and at the top of the code in login.php add the code given below.

```
<?php
echo "hello";die;
?>
```

if you see the hello on the page that means your login.php  working fine. but if you not that means your file is renamed incorrectly sometimes it happens by our editor. the file becomes like **login.php.txt**

**If the filename is correct and you are not getting hello then your server is not working.**

and it seems your code is also fine.

You can also use **POSTMAN** to post data on your page without form and there is **one more alternative ajax**.
../login.php is the wrong path.

**if everything works fine then the error is 100% in the path.**